# data structure in autocad drawings

Tags: tags, autocad

I have to read all the tags out of an autocad drawing with information about the model, the cell, the tagset etcetera in which they were found.

Are the following assumptions correct;

tags are only found in tagsets.
multiple tags within a tagset can have the same name.

tagsets are only found in cells.
the names of tagsets within a cell are unique.

cells are only found within models (and not nested in other cells)
multiple cells within a model can have the same name.

models are only found at the 'top level' in drawings.
the names of models within a drawing are unique.

thanks,

Coen

Answer (score 0):

Go here: http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20.NET%20Developer%27s%20Guide/index.html and navigate to *Basics of the AutoCAD .NET API* --> *Understand the AutoCAD Object Hierarchy* to get an idea of the AutoCAD database structure.

For answers to specific questions search the forums at:

- http://forums.augi.com/forumdisplay.php?f=88
- http://www.theswamp.org/index.php
- http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/AutoCAD-Customization/ct-p/1002

By "tagsets" do you mean collections of attributes in a block or are you talking about tables ("cells")?